# Javascript Update CSS dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dynamic

I am pretty new to Javascript and could do with a hand with a little problem I've got.

I have a PHP script which loads varying amount of images from a database - all 150px wide - and displaying them in a horizontal row. I need to be able to adjust the width of this row to enable scrolling if the items are more than the standard width, or to remove the scrollbar if it is not.

In my PHP I query the database and if the result set returned is greater than 0 I attempt the following in javascript

```
$width = mysql_num_rows($get) * 150;
'<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('container').setAttribute('style', 'width: '.$width.''); 
</script>'
```

container is the holding div ID which is populated by the result set. However I seem unable to dynamically update the width depending on the results of the query.

My HTML is pretty simple

```
<div id="container">
#Call PHP Function
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: And did you echo that piece of javascript further down in the DOM, after the markup for the elements ?

Comment: are you talking about a horizontal scroll bar (left to right)? if your content is too wide the browser will do that by itself. or are you hoping to do some kind of overflow:scroll?

Comment: I echoed that after the div structure closed. And hoping to do something with an overflow scroll

Answer (score 0):

Your quotation marks are the culprit, I think.

Try
`.setAttribute('style', 'width: '+$width);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but your width style should contain pixels:

```
'<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("style", "width: '.$width.'px"); 
</script>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you need JS and not plain CSS. As Kender stated you might solve this problem with `white-space: nowrap;`.

**Sample**

http://jsfiddle.net/8hkLu/

**HTML**

```
<div class="myDynRow">
    <img src="http://www.whats-your-sign.com/images/ZodiacFlowerRose.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.whats-your-sign.com/images/ZodiacFlowerRose.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.whats-your-sign.com/images/ZodiacFlowerRose.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.whats-your-sign.com/images/ZodiacFlowerRose.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="myDynRow">
    <img src="http://www.whats-your-sign.com/images/ZodiacFlowerRose.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.whats-your-sign.com/images/ZodiacFlowerRose.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.whats-your-sign.com/images/ZodiacFlowerRose.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.whats-your-sign.com/images/ZodiacFlowerRose.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.whats-your-sign.com/images/ZodiacFlowerRose.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.whats-your-sign.com/images/ZodiacFlowerRose.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myDynRow {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```